# CSV error when trying to write

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import csv

name = input(': ')
password = input(': ')
age = input(': ')


hello = [name, password, age]
length = len(hello[0])

with open('db.csv', 'a') as testfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
    for y in range(length):
        csv_writer.writerow([x[y] for x in hello])
```

When I run the code above on a separate python file alone it works but whenever I try to put it in my full code it doesn't work. 
What I am trying to do is basically make a register that when I put input it writes to the csv file. I also added a captcha thing for verification because why not.

```
csv_writer.writerow([x[y] for x in hello]):
```

Line 33 ^
The full code v

```
import random
import csv

def reg2():
    print('wip')

def reg1():
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        try:
            name = input('Enter your name: ')
            age = int(input('Enter your age:'))
            password = input('Enter your password: ')
            confirm = input('Confirm Password: ')
            if confirm == password:
                alphabet =''.join(random.choice('0PQRSTUVefghij56789WXYZabcdABCDEFCDrstuvwEFGJ234NOKLMkHImnopqxyz') for i in range(7))
                print(alphabet)
                captcha = input('Enter the words shown above (Not Case Sensitive): ')
                if captcha.capitalize() == alphabet.capitalize() or 'admin'.capitalize():
                    print('Name: ' + name)
                    print('Age: {}'.format(age))
                    print('Password: ' + password)
                    option = input('Enter No to register again. Enter Yes to login.')
                    if option.startswith('N') or option.startswith('n'):
                        reg1()
                    elif option.startswith('Y') or option.startswith('y'):
                        hello = [name, password, age]
                        length = len(hello[0])

                        with open('db.csv', 'a') as testfile:
                            csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
                            for y in range(length):
                                csv_writer.writerow([x[y] for x in hello])
                else:
                    captcha = input('Try again: ')
                    if captcha == alphabet:
                        print('Confirmed. ')
                    else:
                        print('You have tried too many times. Please register again.')
                        reg1()
            else:
                print('Your password is incorrect. Please register again.')
        except ValueError:
            print('Error 666: Please register again.')
reg1()
```

How do I fix this?

The full traceback error is http://pastebin.com/zshHji8i

Comment: What isn't working, is there an error, output incorrect? Post the full traceback if there is an exception.

Comment: Heres the full error http://pastebin.com/zshHji8i

Comment: You should just include your error here, rather than a link... But I don't think `[x[y] for x in hello]` does what you intend. The reason it fails is `age` is a `int` in your full code and a `str` in the sample code. You probably just need `csv_writer.writerow(hello)`. What is your expected output?

Comment: How do I make it work with integers?

Comment: What are you trying to output, `csv_writer.writerow(str(x) for x in hello)`

Comment: Still doesn't work for the full code. It lets integers work on its own though.

Comment: I'll try one more time, what is your expected output?

Comment: Nevermind it worked but it copied it 4 times. The output should've been ace,16,pass

Comment: You don't need the `for y in range(length):`...

Answer (score 0):

```
[...]
length = len(hello[0])

with open('db.csv', 'a') as testfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
    for y in range(length):
        csv_writer.writerow([x[y] for x in hello])
```

So here, "length" is the number of characters in the `name` variable, a few lines later, `for y in range(length)` you're "enumerating" the letters, say you have 6 letters you're getting 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in `y`. A line later `[x[y] for x in hello]` you're asking for the letter `y` for the `name, password, age`, that has no sense for me.

What about a simple:

```
name = input(': ')
password = input(': ')
age = input(': ')


hello = [name, password, age]

with open('db.csv', 'a') as testfile:
    csv.writer(testfile).writerow(hello)
```

Oh, and "hello" is a badly chosen name (we can't deduce what it contains). Oh and "x", "y", and "length" are badly chosen too, (length of what ?). Just choose a nice name for your variables and your bug will become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write:

```
with open('db.csv', 'a') as testfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(hello)
```

`hello` is already a list, there is no need for the construction you used.